# How to add a space to every characters in a dataframe apply on one column python 2.7 pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to add space between each letter from column "col2" on dataframe  df_input

```
df_input 

        col1     col2      col3    col4  
0       ID1      DEAA      69      min-8     
1       ID1      DZD       69      min-8
2       ID3      DAA       54      min-15
3       ID3      ACD       54      min-15
4       ID3      R         54      min-15
5       ID8      U          2       min-40
6       ID8      TCETR      2       min-40
```

I try to get this result :

```
df_output 

        col1     col2           col3    col4  
0       ID1      D E A A        69      min-8     
1       ID1      D Z D          69      min-8
2       ID3      D A A          54      min-15
3       ID3      A C D          54      min-15
4       ID3      R              54      min-15
5       ID8      U              2       min-40
6       ID8      T C E T R      2       min-40
```

Comment: Why Python2.7?!

Comment: I know it is obsolete but it is not depends on me...

Comment: I feel sorry for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.join(' ')
print (df)
  col1       col2  col3    col4
0  ID1    D E A A    69   min-8
1  ID1      D Z D    69   min-8
2  ID3      D A A    54  min-15
3  ID3      A C D    54  min-15
4  ID3          R    54  min-15
5  ID8          U     2  min-40
6  ID8  T C E T R     2  min-40
```